# Should the (teaching) tag be a synonym for (mathematical-pedagogy)?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

Should the [teaching](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teaching) tag be a synonym for [mathematical-pedagogy](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematical-pedagogy)? And if not, what sort of questions would be a good fit for one tag, but not the other? Right now the [teaching](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teaching) tag doesn't have a [usage guidance or a wiki](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/tags/teaching/info) entry.

**Edit to Bump**: Today I noticed the [teaching](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teaching) doesn't have a usage guidance or wiki, and was wondering what it's purpose was, and decided to ask about it on meta only to find that **I already asked about it two years ago!** As a community, can we decide what to do with the [teaching](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teaching) tag?

Comment: Thanks for bringing this up; I am not yet sure what to do, but the tag does not seem useful to me. Not sure why I did not notice it before.

Comment: I would support merging the [teaching] tag into the [mathematical-pedagogy] tag.

Answer (score 4):

Just to provide an answer for folks to vote on if they agree, and to provide something for others to disagree with to spurn discussion:

#### We should make the [teaching](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teaching) tag a synonym for the [mathematical-pedagogy](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematical-pedagogy) tag.

Answer (score 2):

This question was asked 6 years ago. Meanwhile the teaching tag seems less than useful. Therefore, I would like to suggest that a moderator make the teaching tag a synonym for the mathematical pedagogy tag as suggested. No one has objected and it is time.  I am not sure if this request is appropriate as an answer to this question or if it should be a new question, but I am putting it here to get the ball roiling.